# jquery-ui grid Create Read Update Delete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using the jQuery library, not any other JavaScript library, if you were to create a grid input for your users, one that allowed users to insert new data, change the description of existing data and delete data, would you do that using an html table with html tr and td tags, or is there some other method of displaying a sheet of data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at a grid plugin, such as [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).

Comment: Thanks, but I have the feeling that my client is going to want a lot of customization.  So I don't feel comfortable handing the data off to a plugin.  Not that there's anything wrong with that...

Comment: No problem - you may just want to have a quick look at this one, though. It is very customizable and you may find it flexible enough to meet your needs.

Comment: @cfPhillipSenn - Glad to see you accepted this as an answer. As far as jQuery grid libraries go, this is, by far, the best.